# Evaluating $\int \frac{1}{x\sqrt{x^4-4}} dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I am having trouble evaluating
$$\int \dfrac{1}{x\sqrt{x^4-4}} dx$$

I tried making $a = 2$, $u = x^{2}$, $du = 2x dx$ and rewriting the integral as:
$$\dfrac{1}{2} \int \dfrac{du}{\sqrt{u^2-a^2}} $$
But I believe something is not right at this step (perhaps when changing from $dx$ to $du$)?

I end up with:
$${1\over 4} \operatorname{arcsec} \dfrac{1}{2}x^{2} + C$$

Any help would be appreciated, I feel I am only making a simple mistake.  Also, for some reason, on WA, it is showing an answer involving $\tan^{-1}$ but I do not see an $a^{2} + u^{2}$ possibility. Note that I do know how sometimes (different) inverse trig functions when integrated are equal.

Ex: $$\int \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{e^{2x}-1}} dx = \arctan{\sqrt{e^{2x}-1}} + C = \operatorname{arcsec}(e^{x}) + C $$

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+of+1%2F%28x+sqrt%28x%5E4+-+4%29%29. Press: Show Steps.

Comment: As noted in my original post, I already checked WA. I was looking for an easier way since there should be a direct substitution with an $a$ and a $u$, rather than jumping through hoops with 3-4 substitutions. Correct me if I'm wrong though.

Comment: Your first substitution is not correct. You have $du=2x\,dx$, but you want to replace $dx\over x$. Use ${dx\over x} = {du\over 2 u}$. This gives $\int {du\over u\sqrt {u^2-4}}$; which is an $\rm arcsec$ form.

Comment: @DavidMitra I understand to use $dx\over {x}$ but where do you get $dx\over {x}$ = $du\over {2u}$ rather than equals $du\over {2x}$?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You did not make the substitution correctly (your substitution would work as you wrote it if $x$ were originally upstairs).

But the choice you made for $u$ will work:

You have $u=x^2$ and $du=2x\,dx$.

From   $du=2x\,dx$,  you have, dividing both sides by $2x^2$ 
$$\tag{1}{du\over 2x^2}={x\,dx\over x^2}.$$
Substituting $u=x^2$ on the left hand side of $(1)$ and simplifying the right hand side, we have
 $$ \color{maroon}{{du\over 2 u}}=\color{maroon}{{dx\over x}}.$$ Substituting into the integral gives $$\int {\color{maroon}{dx}\over\color{maroon} x \sqrt{ x^4-4}}= \int {\color{maroon}{du}\over\color{maroon}{ 2u}\sqrt {u^2-4}}
 $$ which is an $\rm arcsec$ form.

Comment: What would be your final answer then? It seems it would be the same as mine.  I am still not entirely sure how you jumped from $du = 2x dx$ to the line below it with $du \over{2x^2}.$ Mind elaborating? I see the x cancel out on the RHS and the substitution of u in the line below it - it's the line above "Substituting into the integral" that is still puzzling me.

Comment: What jumped out at you to divide both sides by $2x^{2}?$ To try and get a $dx\over {x}$ term on the RHS?

Comment: @jay Yes, we needed to write $dx\over x$ in terms of $u$.

Comment: When I differentiate 

$${1\over 4} \operatorname{arcsec} \dfrac{1}{2}x^{2} + C$$

I get the original, I must have just been careless in the beginning by forgetting the $u$ term on the bottom of the inside.

Answer (score 0):

$$I:=\int \frac{dx}{x \sqrt{x^4 -4}} $$

let $x=\sqrt{2} y$ then $dx =\sqrt{x} dy$
$$I=\frac{1}{2}\int \frac{dy}{y \sqrt{y^4 -1}} $$

let $y=\frac{1}{t} $ $dy =-\frac{dt}{t^2}$ notice $t =\frac{\sqrt{2}}{x}$
$$I=\frac{-1}{2}\int \frac{t dt}{t^2 \sqrt{\frac{1}{t^4} -1}} =\frac{-1}{2}\int \frac{t dt}{ \sqrt{1 -t ^4}} $$

let $t^2 =\sin(u)$ $2t dt =\cos(u)du$

$$I =\frac{-1}{4}u+C=\frac{-1}{4}\arcsin(t^2)+C =\frac{-1}{4} \arcsin( \frac{2}{x^2})+C $$